# Docker errors in Rust (Rust SSL)

Tags: docker, rust

Rust upload file error
Failed to connect to host: the handshake failed: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1916:: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error using reqwest in a rust application running in an empty docker image `FROM scratch` instead of running for example alpine.

Per default reqwest will use the system TLS implementation to initiate a TLS connection, but as I was using the empty `FROM scratch` image, there (obviously) was no system implementation there.

My solution was to use the `rustls-tls` cargo feature to compile and use the tls implementation written in rust which is cooler anyway.

```ini
reqwest = { version = "0.11", default-features = false, features = ["rustls-tls"] }
```